# Invoke PowerShell script error

Tags: powershell

I've created a script which will send sms from a file which has phone numbers. Now I am trying to invoke the same by `Invoke-Command` I am getting success message but I am not getting the SMS. When I am using the same file and running it manually I am getting SMS.

```cs
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-Location g:
$Date= (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
$OutputFile2 = "\\XXX\yyy\SendTextMsg\" + $Date + "_sms.txt"
$SendTextMsgExe = ".\\XXX\yyy\SendTextMsg\SendTextMsg.exe $OutputFile2"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXX -ScriptBlock {$Args[0]} -Args $SendTextMsgExe
```

Comment: put your codes in the comment into your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted will simply echo the value of `$SendTextMsgExe` on the remote host, because you defined it as a single string. For executing a single command string you'd need to use `Invoke-Expression` inside the scriptblock. However, doing that is [not recommended](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/). It's better to pass command and arguments separately, invoke them via the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-3.0#special-operators) and use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-3.0) for passing the arguments to the command.

```
# define $params as a list of values (comma separated):
# $params = 'C:\path\to\some.txt', '-x', 'x_value', ...
$params = $OutputFile2
$SendTextMsgExe = "\\XXX\yyy\SendTextMsg\SendTextMsg.exe"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXX -ScriptBlock {
    Param($cmd, $param)
    & $cmd @param
} -Args $SendTextMsgExe, $params
```

But even with that your code probably still won't work, since you're invoking an executable from a UNC path (using a text file from an UNC path too), so you should be running into the [2nd hop problem](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/).

If you can't use the CredSSP approach described in that article you need to map the UNC path to a drive with explicit credentials and then run the command from the network drive:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
$OutputFile2 = "${Date}_sms.txt"
$SendTextMsgExe = '\\XXX\yyy\SendTextMsg\SendTextMsg.exe'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName XXX -ScriptBlock {
    Param($cmd, $param)

    $path = Split-Path $cmd -Parent
    $exe  = Split-Path $cmd -Leaf

    $d = New-PSDrive -Name 'X' -Root $path -Credential $using:cred -Persist -PSProvider FileSystem
    Set-Location $d.Root

    & ".\$exe" @param

    Remove-PSDrive $d
} -Args $SendTextMsgExe, $OutputFile2
```